# Question about the definition of the principle argument of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that the argument function of the complex number is a multi-valued function , so we restrict its domain to be some thing like $\theta \in [0, 2\pi[ $

But when we define the principle argument we say that $\theta \in [-\pi , \pi[$

My question :

Why it is not correct to say the the principle argument is $\theta \in [0, 2\pi[ $ ? Or any interval of length  $2\pi$ Without cutting the real axis more than once ?

In other words why should we get ride of the negative real axis from the domain ?

Comment: Any ray (half-line) starting from the origin is fine. Using the  the negative real axis is just a convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it *could* be defined as a value in $[0 , 2\pi[$ or even $[-\frac{12}{5}\pi, -\frac{2}{5}\pi [$.

it is chosen to be $[-\pi , \pi[$ because:

1. it is simply a convention
2. simple transformation from/to polar coordinates
3. historically chosen by community